# displaying an image saved as a Blob in a MySql DB

Tags: php, mysql, blob

Im creating a blog and the little bit of code below is where the blog geets printed out.
I've got a blob saved in my mysql database and im trying to turn it back into an image.
the imageName, imageType, imageSize, imageContect all receive values when i run my code. The problem is that the imageContent variable displays a load of random characters rather then an image. it seems that the reason for this is the headers but i've no idea what to do. can anyone help me to recode the image. thanks

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{

    echo "name ".$row['imageName'].'<BR>';
    echo "type ".$row['imageType'].'<BR>';
    echo "size ".$row['imageSize'].'<BR>';

    echo '<B>'.$row['blogTitle'].'</B><br />';

    echo '<A HREF = http://www.alcaeos.com/blog/displayblogProcess.php?mode=edit&blogID='.$row['blogID'].'>Edit</A>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';       
    echo '<A HREF = http://www.alcaeos.com/blog/displayblogProcess.php?mode=delete&blogID='.$row['blogID'].'>Delete</A><BR />';


    echo $row['blog'].'<br />';

    header("Content-length:".$row['imageSize']);
    header("Content-type:.".$row['imageType']);
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$row['imageName']);
    echo $row['imageContent'].'---------<br /><br /><br />';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fairly simple example of displaying an image stored as a blob.

```
<?php

require_once ('./includes/db.inc.php'); // Connect to the db.

//let the browser know its an image
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

// Make the query.
$query = "SELECT thumbnail FROM items where item_id=" . $_GET['item_id'];
$result = @mysql_query ($query);

if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
  echo $row['thumbnail'];
  }

mysql_close(); // Close the database connection.
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Skip the Content-length and Content-disposition, just use Content-type and set it to a valid MIME type.

Assuming they're JPEGs, you'd do this:

```
header( 'Content-type: image/jpeg' );
```

Check out [this link too](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Display_an_image_stored_in_a_database__PHP_-16637.html)